# Android OS with VR in future

Tags: applications

I've heard a rumor that Facebook has been working on VR and have successfully launched one product, Oculus Rift. Have any VR projects been released or announced for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already two VR projects running on Android.

Google Cardboard ([google-cardboard](/questions/tagged/google-cardboard)) provides a cheap way of strapping your phone to your face and a software platform for app authors to add VR capability to their apps. In its original form, it's a template that you make out of cardboard and add a couple of cheap lenses to, but several manufacturers have started shipping low-cost "VR headsets" based on this design.

Samsung Gear VR is a Samsung project developed with Oculus VR. It uses the screen from any of this year's high-end Samsung phones, along with extra sensors provided by the headset device, to provide a mobile VR platform offering more immersion and presence than Google Cardboard. It's a product you can buy in shops now.

Facebook hasn't launched a VR device. Their investment in VR has been to buy pioneers Oculus VR, which is responsible for developing the Gear VR for Samsung, as well as the Oculus Rift, their PC-based VR product.